# In which language is made a page ".shl"?

Tags: html

Pages like this:

http://info.abril.com.br/noticias/carreira/ibm-da-curso-gratuito-de-ingles-a-distancia-06092010-37.shl

are make in which language? Is "shl" a language? I didn't found more about..

Comment: Looking at the source shows it is HTML with a lot of java. The URL is probably being re-written. Do you have other examples?

Comment: shl can be produced by **any** language based on server settings

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with shared libraries? Like [shl_load](http://docs.hp.com/en/B2355-90130/shl_load.3X.html) or something?

Comment: @Benjamin many pages on this same website have a final ".shl"

Comment: sorry, I meant on other sites?

Answer (score 2):

File extensions on the web can be misleading. Webservers can be configured to treat extensions any way they want. There's nothing stopping a webmaster from naming all their HTML files ".exe" and calling their PHP scripts ".aspx"

Check that server's output headers. maybe there's a language signature. e.g. PHP can put in an "X-Powered-By" header if the webmaster so chooses.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have to be a specific language, it depends on the configuration of the webserver. I would hunt for clues on the page, as the file extension is no help concerning finding out the underlying technology.

Answer (score 0):

Well all webpages - including the example page you link to - are written in HTML and javascript. What the server-side language is that generates (or simply returns) that HTML and javascript could be practically anything.

However, the file ending .shl doesn't necessarily mean the server side language is .shl related. You can have your URLs ending with anything you like.

As far as what .shl file extension might be, I don't know. A google search throws up this: "Inno Setup String Tables file format" but i have no idea what this is.

Comment: A further Google search shows that InnoSetup is an installer for Windows programs. No relation.